# "why are u putting ur coat on for?" vs "What are you putting your coat on for?"

Tags: grammar

This comes from a classic song "Baby it's cold outside". In one of James Taylor's versions he says *"why are you putting your coat on for?"* and it just got me because I had always thought you would say:

> **Why** + are you doing that?

or

> **What** + are doing that **+ for**?

never

> **Why** + are you doing that **+ for**?

So, is the song really wrong?

Comment: It is not normal syntax (if that's what he sings: might it be a mishearing, _wha'_ for _what_? I don't know). But songs often use non-standard expressions.

Comment: You know, Colin, it might well be a mishearing. In fact I got the lyrics online.
But it answers to say that's non-standard. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be standard, but it would be something people say either because it is local or personal idiom or because they switch mentally from "Why … ?" to "What … for?" partway through speaking.

The song tells a story. Is telling a story about people who don't speak standard English without any slips wrong?

(Assuming that it is in fact that rather than a transcription error).

On a related note, the time signature of some early published versions (which don't have that line at all, if I recall correctly) were marked as to be played in the tempo *Loesserando*, which isn't a standard musical tempo but a play on the composer's name. Does that count as "wrong" or as brilliant?